# How to change samesite policy for cookie-universal-nuxt

Tags: cookies, nuxt.js

I'm using [cookie-universal-nuxt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-universal-nuxt) on my project and getting lots of "samesite" attribute set to "none" error.
how to change it's samesite policy to "lax"?

error message:

**Cookie “x” will be soon rejected because it has the “SameSite” attribute set to “None” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some tweaking found the way.

```
this.$cookies.set('x', this.x, {
     path: '/',
     maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
     sameSite: 'lax'
});
```